# How to parse and get the first match with regex substitute for optional string patterns

Tags: python-3.x

I have 9 char ids that I need to extract from the texts, the actual ids always start with FRX but this data is messy and can have cases like FRX,FRR,FRK etc. which I'm handling below. It's working for 95% of the cases but the following cases are not working for me and give the second match instead of the first one.

```
data1 = 'PAYOFF LOAN FRX 121130 BORROWER LOUIS TOTH PROPERTY 12565 SILVER FXCT ROSWELL GA 30075 DEBIT REF 113566802'
data2 = 'FN-19031263 PO-FRX-101486 FRX-1 .0148 6/ODIN NEW HORIZON REAL ESTAT.E FUND LP/CHICAGO TITLE/7028368000/PROPAD DR-508 ELM CREST PLACE DEBIT REF 2020021000674826'

id = re.sub(r'.*f[rx][kxrcz]+', 'FRX', data, count=1, flags=re.IGNORECASE).replace(' ','').replace('-','')[:9]
```

Gives

```
id1 - FRXTROSWE
id2 - FRX1.0148
```

The desired output is

```
id1 - FRX121130
id2 - FRX101486
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way using `re.findall`:

```
"".join(re.findall("(f[rx][kxrcz])\D*(\d+)", data1, re.I)[0])
"".join(re.findall("(f[rx][kxrcz])\D*(\d+)", data2, re.I)[0])
```

Output:

```
FRX121130
FRX101486
```

Comment: hi Chris, this is still missing a few cases like this one `69638699 TRUNG LAM NGUYEN FRX08 /5424 DEBIT REF 2021050400347901` where the desired id is - `FRX085424`, how should I incorporate this in the current logic? your suggestion gives `FRX08` which is not the complete id

Comment: @adityabhandari So what is the rule of a thumb here? any string with `FRX`-list string that is followed by 6 digits, regardless of non-numeric string in between the digits?

Comment: Yes that would work, the id is always 9 digits, F[RX][RKCX] 3 characters follwed by xxxxxx 6 digits, so I would still like to capture the incorrect ones with whitespaces and special characters in between. Thanks for your help really appreciate it.